# Youtube-dl batch file - "TypeError: %c requires int or char"

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, youtube-dl

When I run a batch file containing the following:

```
@echo off
set /p userinput=C:/youtube-dl.exe -o "%%cd%%/%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" 
C:/youtube-dl.exe  -o "%%cd%%/%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" %userinput%
pause
```

I get the following error: "TypeError: %c requires int or char"

It seems the problem is with the %cd% variable where I want the program to take the directory from which it was launched.

I have made sure to wrap the variable in double percent signs, so I don't see what the issue is. This executes just fine if I manually type it in Command Prompt (without the %userinput% section and of course with single percent signs for the variables).

Here's an image for the full console window:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
set /p userinput=C:/youtube-dl.exe -o "%cd%/%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" 
C:/youtube-dl.exe -o "%cd%/%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" %userinput%
pause
```

The difference is that `%cd%`, which is an environment variable, should be wrapped with **only one** pair of percent signs.

Source: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme

> However you should not touch %'s that are not plain characters, e.g. environment variables for expansion should stay intact: -o "C:\%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\%%(title)s.%%(ext)s".